# Find no of days remaining on current month from given date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I just want to calculate the number of days remaining from given date

Ex:

if the date is '02/01/2016' then the remaining days on the given month is '28'

if 03/05/2016 then '25' days...

I tried the below

```
SELECT DATEPART(DD,'03/05/2016')  it given me only 5 days
```

Comment: you are using both Oracle & SQL Server ?

Comment: Just a heads up, `DATEPART()` is returning the part of a date specified in ARG1. Thus, `DATEPART(DD,'3/5/2016')` will return the day part of that date, which is 5. It's not 5 days, it's the 5th day of march. `DATEDIFF()` is what you want to use, and there are some great answers below on how to do so. Cheers!

Comment: I removed the Oracle tag because the syntax is clearly SQL Server.

Comment: Assuming the month is the first part of your dates, so 03/05/2016 is March 5... March has 31 days. How are there 25 days remaining? (By the way, this applies both to Oracle and to SQL Server.)

Answer (score 3):

**SQLServer specific since you mentioned version as well:**

```
 select DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)))
```

you just need to find last date of given month and calculating datediff is easy,Below expression does the same

```
  DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))
```

**On 2012,it is much easier:**

```
select datediff(day,getdate(),EOMONTH(GETDATE()))
```

Comment: there are syntax error on the query that you posted

Comment: @Squirrel:thank you,i dont have SQL server when posting to test,i tested it now

Answer (score 1):

for SQL Server

```
select DATEDIFF(DAY, 
                GETDATE(), 
                DATEADD(MONTH, 
                        DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 
                        0)
               ) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you also tagged Oracle:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY( DATE '2016-02-01' ) - DATE '2016-02-01'
         AS days_remaining
FROM   DUAL;
```

**Output**:

```
DAYS_REMAINING
--------------
            28
```

Answer (score 0):

check below,

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '02/05/2016'
SELECT CASE WHEN month(@date) IN (1,3,5,7,8,10,12) THEN 31 - DATEPART(DD,@date)
            WHEN month(@date) IN (4,6,9,11) THEN 30 - DATEPART(DD,@date)
            ELSE 28 - DATEPART(DD,@date)
            END
```

note: in above code leap year is not taken into account

edited: leap year proof version

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '02/05/2016'
DECLARE @leap_year bit = 0

IF ((YEAR(@date) % 4 = 0 AND YEAR(@date) % 100 <> 0) OR YEAR(@date) % 400 = 0)
   SET @leap_year = 1

SELECT CASE WHEN MONTH(@date) IN (1,3,5,7,8,10,12) THEN 31 - DATEPART(DD,@date)
        WHEN MONTH(@date) IN (4,6,9,11) THEN 30 - DATEPART(DD,@date)
        WHEN MONTH(@date) = 2 AND @leap_year = 1 then 29 - DATEPART(DD,@date)
        ELSE 28 - DATEPART(DD,@date)
        END
```

Comment: Not `leap year` proof ? Why not make it handle leap year ?

Comment: @Squirrel, you're right, will do when ever have a free minute.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the Trick. hope it helps. My assumptions are that you are using SQL Server 2008.
The trick here is to get the first day of the next month which will always be 01-NextMonth-Year

> DATEADD(mm, 1, @Date)

and subtract 1 day from it to get the last day of current month

> DATEADD(dd, - 1, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(mm, 1, @Date), 121) +
>   '01')

Now DateDiff between Input Date and Last day of the input month will give you remaining days in the month

> DATEDIFF(dd, @Date, @LastDateofMonth)

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = GETDATE()
DECLARE @LastDateofMonth DATE

SELECT @LastDateofMonth = DATEADD(dd, - 1, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(mm, 1, @Date), 121) + '01')

SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, @Date, @LastDateofMonth)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MyDATE as datetime;


SELECT @MYDATE = '19960423';

--wind back to first of month
--add on one month
--now calculate days from original date, this is always '1 to high' so subtract 1

SELECT 
   DATEDIFF(day, @mydate, DATEADD(month, 1,D ATEADD(day, 1 - DAY(@MYDATE), @MYDATE))) - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this one to calculate the diffreance from today

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,getdate() ,EOMONTH(GETDATE()))
```

or this to calculate the date from a param

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,@date ,EOMONTH(GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

With SQL 2012's new function EOMONTH() you could try:

```
DECLARE @Date date = '2017-08-08'
select datediff (dd, @Date, EOMONTH(@Date)) as DaysRemaining
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select DATEDIFF(DD, GETDATE(),GETDATE())
select DATEDIFF(DD,'2015/10/05','2015/10/07')
```

Comment: you can try in sql sever

Comment: But how does that gives `no of days remaining on current month from given date` ?

Comment: where I use current month ?